# MySQL left join where 2nd object is AND is

Tags: mysql, sql, count, where-clause, having-clause

## Database

**products**

```sql
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(128) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**tags**

```sql
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name          | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**products_tags**

```
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tag_id     | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

### Goal

Return *products* that are tagged by 2+ tags, for example "present" and "birthday".

It might look something like:

```sql
SELECT p.name FROM products p
LEFT JOIN products_tags p_t ON p_t.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = p_t.tag_id
WHERE <what-is-the-condition?>
```

Missing the correct condition that would select by tags which are both present and birthday.

Something like:

```
WHERE t.name = 'present' AND t.name = 'birthday';
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table `tags` is not needed.
Join `products` to `products_tags`, `group by` product and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name 
FROM products p INNER JOIN products_tags p_t 
ON p_t.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: I will mark this as answer since it allows specifying 2+ distinct tags. I haven't mention this in the question, but this is what I was aiming for, since my back-end code dynamically picks the tags.

Answer (score 2):

YOu can use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN products_tags p_t ON p_t.product_id = p.id
INNER JOIN tags t            ON t.id = p_t.tag_id
WHERE t.tag IN ('present', 'birthday')    -- either one or the other
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2                       -- both are present in the group
```

This assumes no duplicate tag per product. Otherwise, you need to change the `HAVING` clause to:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query specific to any tags then WHERE is a must. I think your question is not correct as per your desire result.

```
SELECT products.name
    FROM  products
    Join products_tags ON products_tags.product_id = products.id
    
    JOIN tags ON tags.id = products_tags.tag_id
    WHERE tags.name = 'present' OR tags.name='birthday' GROUP BY products.name
```